# Non cyclic group of order 125 which has an element of order 25.

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, direct-product

I am trying to find a non cyclic group of order 125 which has an element of order 25.

I know product of cyclic groups can be used, but I am not sure whether an element of order 25 exists.

is there any generalized method to come up with examples for any given group with any given order? like a non cyclic group of order 63, with element of order 21.

Comment: Not sure if this would work, but maybe try a semi-direct product?

Comment: What about $C_{25} \times C_5$ and  $C_{21} \times C_3$? Consider the element $(1,0)$.

Comment: @SquirtleSquad Yeah you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group: $\mathbb{Z}_{25}\times\mathbb{Z}_{5}$

Order $25$ element: $(1,0)$

In general for non-cyclic group of order $pq$ with $p,q$ **not** coprime you can take $\mathbb{Z}_{p}\times\mathbb{Z}_{q}$ then $(1,0)$ will be of order $p$ as required.

Comment: thanks. will there be element of order q in your general case?

Comment: yes, $(0,1)$, you could also just swap $p,q$

Comment: thanks. it was really stupid of me.